Flutter - FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow is not allowing more than 2 consecutive dots in the TextField
With the below code, if we are entering 3 consecutive dots. All the entered dots got removed.
TextFormField(
              autocorrect: false,
              enableSuggestions: false,
              inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9@,#.]")),
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(20)],
            )

Example:
User entering input: Abc...
What Actually TextField shows in UI: Abc
Expected: Abc...
Note: Faced in iOS, Not tested in Android.

In this case, you'd need to write a custom input formatter.
class CustomInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {


final RegExp _regExp = RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z0-9@,#.]*');

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (_regExp.hasMatch(newValue.text)) {
      return newValue;
    } else {
      return oldValue;
    }
  }
}

Use it in your Code like this
TextFormField(
              autocorrect: false,
              enableSuggestions: false,
              inputFormatters: [
              CustomInputFormatter(),
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(20)],
            )


As per your code, the field is accepting unnecessary characters like ?(){}><
